# Couldn't find executable named rqt_mypkg

Tags: ros, rqt-image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble running my RQT package. The error is:

```
**Couldn't find executable named rqt_mypkg below /home/ros_user/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg

Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/ros_user/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg
[rosrun]   /home/ros_user/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg/src/rqt_mypkg
[rosrun]   /home/ros_user/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg/scripts/rqt_mypkg
[rosrun]   /home/ros_user/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg/include/rqt_mypkg**
```

The catkin_make command is successful and I even tried adding in syntax errors purposely to make sure that the code was fine.
I'm using the *rqt_image_view* package with all the files included from the ros wiki site (I made changes to the path for my package name in files where necessary). Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174177/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-rqt_mypkg/) by [jhinton](https://answers.ros.org/users/18929/jhinton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming from your output that `rqt_mypkg/scripts/rqt_mypkg` is what you actually want to run, make sure it's executable mode (eg. set it `$chmod 755 rqt_mypkg`). `rosrun` is able to find those files but complains that none of them are executable.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jhinton](https://answers.ros.org/users/18929/jhinton/) on 2014-06-23**:
Thanks this helped out a lot. I used $ chmod -R 755 /rqt_mypkg